# can git handle device file?

Tags: git, file, device

In a embedded software project， I want to commit some block or character special file to git.
But i failed. how to change settings in git so that it can automatically detect the change of the files of this type? does git only support normal file and directory?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. At best you can make a hook to create it on checkout.

Comment: Thank you very much!I will do it in your way.